# macOS immediately switching away when changing space

Tags: spaces, mission-control

I use Mission Control Spaces to separate the different applications and projects I'm working on. So, e.g. desktop 1 is email; desktops 8 and 9 are for different customers, etc. And I use ctrl-number keyboard shortcuts to switch between desktops/Spaces.

Mostly this works fine, but sometimes when I switch back to a desktop, macOS immediately switches back to a different desktop (and not necessarily the one that I just came from).

It seems to be tied to a particular desktop: e.g. if it's desktop 1 that's the problem, I can switch to any of desktops 2-9 in any order without problem, but every time I try to switch to desktop 1, it immediately switches away again.

The only fix I've found is to press Ctrl-Up and explicitly select the desktop I want to use to.

Has anyone else experienced this and, more importantly, figured out how to prevent it from happening?

macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, but I've been intermittently experiencing this for years.

Mission control configured:

- to *not* automatically rearrange Spaces based on use
- to *not* switch to a Space with open windows for the application when switching to an application
- to group windows by application
- displays *do not* have separate Spaces

Comment: To partially answer my own question: I've just provoked it again. On this occasion, at least, I clicked a link in an email (desktop 1), which opened a new browser tab in a browser window on a different desktop (desktop 9). And it seems the OS has remembered that it's supposed to be switching away from desktop 1 - every time I switch back to desktop 1, it jumps away from that desktop - although not to the desktop that contains the new browser tab (!)

Comment: And pressing and holding (e.g. for 1-2s) the space-switch keyboard shortcut (ctrl-1, in my case) stops the immediate switch away.Can't believe I've lived with this annoyance for so long and found an acceptable workaround out within 15 minutes of finally bothering to ask for others' input.